# Building a Docker Container with Cetnos7 apache and php.

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose

I'll preface this by saying I am very new to the docker world and despite reading documentation I am still a little confused about a few things.

I want to build a container with centos7 apache and php. I don't want to use an already existing image, want to build a custom container. I have the following folder structure

[image]

My rw/docker/webserver/Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]


RUN yum -y install httpd
RUN systemctl start httpd
RUN systemctl enable httpd
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y libpng-dev curl libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd curl

RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

MY docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '2'

services: 
    webserver: 
        build: ./docker/webserver
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes: 
            - /**PATH**/rw/services:/var/www/html
        links:
            - db

    db: 
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports: 
           - "3306:3306"
        volumes: 
           - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment: 
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=****
```

This fails when docker tries to start httpd with the error
     `ERROR: Service 'webserver' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c systemctl start httpd' returned a non-zero code: 1`

**Q1.** Why is the install failing?
**Q2.** Is the the proper way to do this? Should my dockerfile for centos and apache+php be separate. If yes, how does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. I think `systemctl` may not be provided with CentOS docker image.

Indeed, docker services are not meant to be run as daemons, but in the foreground. Take a look at [apache's original http-foreground shell script](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/c14a031c014aa2219aea2e73786f577300756f0b/2.2/httpd-foreground) for a better understanding of the concept.

Q2. Not that's not the right way IMHO.

Running apache is the job of an [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) script.

So instead of `RUN your-command-to-run-apache`, it would rather be `CMD your-command-to-run-apache`.

Once again, [Apache official repository](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/c14a031c014aa2219aea2e73786f577300756f0b/2.2/Dockerfile) can give you some clue about this.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still a little confused. How would I build linux image and install apache and php on that?

Comment: Following `docker`'s philosophy, each service should be run in a separate container, which means `PHP` should have  its own. Anyway, if you choose to stick with the above example, you don't need to have `apache` running when enabling a module or installing a php extension.

Comment: By the way, I can't see how the instruction `RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd curl` could succeed in any way. Indeed `docker-php-ext-install` is a helper script [provided by PHP Official image](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/47041839085c4feaa7f7e6b2732a993a98471a20/7.2-rc/stretch/apache/docker-php-ext-install) and is not part of Apache image.

Comment: So, would you have multiple services in the docker-compose and build your centos -> then apache -> then php? I'm still conceptually trying to get my head around this.

Comment: No, actually each service (`apache`, `php`,`mysql`) is built upon it's own centOS image. You have to forget the `os` approach and adopt the `service` point of view, each service is a linux container running standalone, and linked to other services.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I see what you're saying now.

Answer (score 0):

To my eyes these kinds of Dockerfiles look too old as they try to map the external docker daemon inside the container. That's a workaround as a systemd daemon cannot be run separately in a container.

Instead I am using the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script. The docker systemctl.py can parse the normal *.service files to know how to start and stop services. You can register it as the CMD of an image in which case it will look for all the systemctl-enabled services - those will be started and stopped in the correct order.

There are even some testcases for the LAMP stack available, so it should work in your case quite smoothly. The systemctl.py script is compatible with the systemd systemctl as much as that one simply overwrite the /usr/bin/systemctl inside the image - and all the non-docker installation instructions will work for docker builds.